# Words for political without party affiliation?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage

I'm struggling to find the right word to describe a campaign I'm starting.

I want to influence public policy around an agenda in a party neutral manner.

Apolitical and non-political feel wrong. The cultural bias is British English.

**Update**
I'm aiming to be as socially inclusive as possible, so some of the great suggestions so far have the wrong nuance.

Comment: Perhaps you should play on a synonym for "party":  faction, association, caucus, denomination, league, syndicate, machine, circle, band, guild, society, alliance, coalition, clique.  Actually, "non-denominational" might work, or a play on one of the other words.  Or you might call it a "dissociation".

Comment: "Unalliance" might work.

Comment: Or you could just say that you're "not party-cular".

Answer (score 7):

You can often describe a "neutral" but politically-inflected organization or initiative as **nonpartisan**. Common usages might include "the nonpartisan ballot initiative" or "nonpartisan think-tank."

Comment: That's definitely a good answer, but I'm looking to be as socially inclusive as possible, and nonpartisan is possibly a bit high-brow. Think-tank is good inspiration for shaping my language.

Comment: *Nonpartisan* is tricky, however, because just as a person can be registered as an "independent" voter but strongly favor one political party or another, an organization can be legally *non-partisan* but work in step with one or another political party, even beyond ideological alignment— the Center for American Progress and the Heritage Foundation are more deeply in bed with the US Democratic and Republican parties than their fellow travelers in Washington at, say, the Urban Institute or CSIS.

Comment: @choster That's a useful point, but I think it's more a question of whether someone is *accurately* describing themselves or another as nonpartisan, and we could raise that question about any descriptor. When describing a US non-profit organization technically barred from political activity, for example, "nonpartisan" isn't really a legal term -- it's a shorthand for a quality *presumed* to apply to a 501(c)(3) organization.

Answer (score 6):

You could describe yourself as ***[independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_politician)***

Comment: That would suggest an intent to run for office to me, I'm trying to convey the idea of influencing politicians without becoming one, but at the same time being honest about social change being a political process.

Comment: Actually (inspired by ericgregory) independent think-tank might capture the idea, but feels a bit elitist.

Comment: @PhilLello sounds a bit like movements like 38 Degrees - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/38_Degrees - who describe themselves as "an independent British not-for-profit political-activism organisation that campaigns on a wide range of issues."

Comment: See also "grass-roots movement", although this may require a critical mass of members before it can be described thus.

Comment: @PhilLello Independent is very commonly used to refer to voters of neither major party (sometimes libertarian is separate). That's legally what they are called here in NC.

Answer (score 2):

What about ***[civic activism or engagement](http://www.nytimes.com/ref/college/collegespecial2/coll_aascu_defi.html):***

> - Civic engagement means working to make a difference in the civic life of our communities and developing the combination of knowledge, skills, values and motivation to make that difference. ***It means promoting the quality of life in a community, through both political and non-political processes.***

(The New York Times)

***[Civic vs civil](http://grammarist.com/words/civic-vs-civil/):***

> - Civic is an adjective which describes an object or person as having to do with a city or town, or that the object was created or came from a city or town. ***It specifically has to do with the government of a city or the duties involved with running a city.***
> - ***Civil is an adjective describing an object or a person relating to citizenship or a citizen (i.e., a member of the community) as opposed to the military or church leadership.***  Civil rights are things that every person of the community has the right to. This term is not discussing human rights, which are things each human on Earth is entitled to, without the need to be a member of a community.

(The Grammarist)

Comment: The definition is perfect; unfortunately British English tends not to use the word civic. Civil seems irreconcilably linked to civil servant/service/etc.

Answer (score 0):

I mean, there's no linguistic reason you couldn't be political with no party affiliation.

You could say you are **Non-Party-Political**

Answer (score 0):

> I want to influence public policy around an agenda in a party neutral manner.

*I want to be an activist.*

> [Activism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activism) consists of efforts to promote, impede, or direct social, political, economic, or environmental change, or stasis with the desire to make improvements in society and to correct social injustice. –Wiki